# Safely adding/subtracting days to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a function which takes two `DateTime` parameters and I have to add separate offsets to these date. I know that `DateTime` has a `AddDays` function to add days to a date and it throws an exception if `DateTime` is less than `MinValue` or greater than `MaxValue`.

Now I want to do a safe check whether adding/subtracting the following number of days to a `DateTime` can cause over/under flow or not.

```
safeStartDate = (startDate == DateTime.MinValue || startDate == DateTime.MaxValue) ? startDate : startDate.AddDays(startDateOffset);
safeEndDate = (endDate == DateTime.MaxValue || endDate == DateTime.MinValue) ? endDate : endDate.AddDays(enDateOffset);
```

By doing this, I am making it one level exception free but date can be `DateTime.Max - 1` and while trying to add offset it throws an exception. I am looking a better way that whether the final values over/under flows without doing the actual calculation, in order to prevent exception.

Comment: Are such overflow possibilities in your application particularly frequent? Would catching/handling the exception actually cause a _measurable_ performance impact for your usage?

Comment: You can try substracting Datetime.MaxValue - date and compare it with your offset

Comment: yeah, the overflows are pretty frequent and that's why my first preference is to avoid try catch.

Comment: @RaviGupta, have you checked my answer? It doesn't use the `try{}catch{}` approach and from my tests it's 500 times faster than it for 10000 iterations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If catch is not called very often you can do:

```
try
{
    safeDate = dt.AddDays(days);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    safeDate = date;
}
```

Alternatively,

```
var maxDays = (DateTime.MaxValue - dt).TotalDays;
safeDate = (days <= maxDays) ? dt.AddDays(days) : dt;
```

Or if there are negative days:

```
var maxDays = (DateTime.MaxValue - dt).TotalDays;
var minDays = (DateTime.MinValue - dt).TotalDays;
return (minDays <= days && days <= maxDays) ? dt.AddDays(days) : dt;
```

Or just use the method from [Rawling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136872/1245027): `CanAddDays(dt, days) ? dt.AddDays(days) : dt`

The try/catch version is about 25% faster if you don't catch and about 1000x slower if you do.  So, if you expected to catch more than about 1 time in every 5000 uses, then use the second version.

Comment: Whats the problem if its called very often? But its being called pretty often.

Comment: Try/Catch is expensive; it's very slow if called lots.

Comment: And also I have 2 datetime, so I have to put two separate try/catch back to back.

Comment: Or just create a method and call that for each.

Comment: This is going to be by far the easiest way. It also means you don't have to worry about the fact that you should really be using System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime rather than DateTime.MaxValue, depending on the current culture.

Comment: To be clear: Try/Catch is ONLY EXPENSIVE IF AN EXCEPTION ACTUALLY GETS THROWN. Otherwise, it's very cheap indeed.

Comment: My quick test suggests that the try/catch approach is ~400 times slower than the spare version.

Comment: The try/catch is quicker if you don't catch.

Comment: The documentation suggests that you would only get an  ArgumentOutOfRangeException, so better just to catch that rather than all exceptions.

Comment: But what about if offset is a negative integer ... your second solution will not work in that case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to check whether you can add a given number of days to a given `DateTime` without causing an overflow:

```
bool CanAddDays(DateTime dt, int days)
{
    double maxDaysToAdd = (DateTime.MaxValue - dt).TotalDays;
    double minDaysToAdd = (DateTime.MinValue - dt).TotalDays;
    return days <= maxDaysToAdd && days >= minDaysToAdd;
}
```

Comment: To be *completely* safe, you should really check against `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime` for the applicable culture. In the unlikely event you're not using the Julian calendar. :)

Comment: ... I'll take your word for that :p

Comment: I'm not 100% but I think they should be ``<=`` and ``>=``. (might not be true as they are doubles)

Comment: @Scroog You're right, if the interval is a whole number of days then adding said whole number should be legal.

Comment: I verified the source code (.NET and .NET Core), this is pretty much what .NET itself is internally doing when you are adding timespan to datetime. +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime Max = DateTime.MaxValue;
Max.Subtract(Now);
int DaysToAdd = 1000;//or something else
if (Max.Day > DaysToAdd) Now.AddDays(DaysToAdd);//add
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following method:

```
private static DateTime AddDays(DateTime dateTime, int days)
{
    var daysTimeSpanTicks = (new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0)).Ticks;
    return (days >= 0) ?
        (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks < dateTime.Ticks + daysTimeSpanTicks) ? dateTime : dateTime.AddDays(days) :
        (dateTime.Ticks + daysTimeSpanTicks < 0) ? dateTime : dateTime.AddDays(days);
}
```

A sample usage is:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime safe = AddDays(date, -100);
```